# requirePaddingNewLinesAfterUseStrict in ESLint

Tags: javascript, eslint, jscs

Now the [JSCS](http://jscs.info/) project was merged with ESLint and the JSCS  linter is deprecated I'm still having a hard time trying to figure out how to replace certain rules.
Specifically, JSCS has this rule [`requirePaddingNewLinesAfterUseStrict`](http://jscs.info/rule/requirePaddingNewLinesAfterUseStrict) that does what the name suggests: requires you to add a new line after `"use strict"`.
I've searched the ESLint rules but couldn't find an equivalent.
Is there maybe a plugin that adds a similar rule to ESLint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of ESLint 3.5.0, you should be able to use the ESLint rule [lines-around-directive](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/lines-around-directive) to add new line after `"use strict";`

In your `.eslintrc` file, add the following to the `rules` object:

`"lines-around-directive": "error",`